# Same C source, different output

Tags: c++, c, compilation, binary, mingw

I've found an old C source code that I've implemented several years ago, and also its compiled binary executable.

In a comment I wrote that the compilation command was:

```
gcc -O3 source.c -o executable -lm
```

So I recompiled it but the new executable is different (in size) from the old one.

In fact if I run the new and the old executable they give me different results: the old executable returns the same result returned years ago, while the new one returns a different result.

**My goal would be to be able to recompile the source and obtain the same executable as the old (or at least an executable that produce exactly the same result).**

I'm sure that I run the two programs with the same parameters, and that the code does **not** use **threads** at all. The only particular thing is that I need random integers, but I use my own function to produce them just in case to be sure that the sequence of random numbers is always the same (and of course I always use the same seed).

```
unsigned int seed = 0;
void set_srand(unsigned int aseed) {
    seed = aseed;
}

int get_rand() {
    seed = seed * 0x12345 + 0xABC123;
    int j = (seed >> 0x10) & RAND_MAX;
    return j;
}
```

(I thought this was copied from some library).

So what can it be? Maybe the OS where the compilation is done (the original one was under WinXP, now I'm trying under both Win7 and Ubuntu), but I've always only used **MinGW**. So maybe the version of MinGW? If this is the case, I'm in trouble because I don't remember which version I've used several years ago.

Libraries that I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
```

What I do are only string operations and computation like `pow()`, `sqrt()`, multiplication and plus/minus, in order to apply an heuristic optimization algorithm to solve approximately an NP-hard problem: the results are both solutions of the problem, but their fitness differs.

Comment: can you share a bit more about the type of output that your program produces? and exactly how it is different between the versions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in code. Relying on undefined or implementation specific behaviour perhaps?

Comment: If you want the same executable, use the same version of compiler that you used for the old one. If your program is deterministic but you get different results, it would suggest that either one of the compilers is bugged (unlikely), or your own code has undefined behaviour. Is the old executable compiled with debugging symbols? Try running in debugger and see where the execution diverges. (oops, just noticed that the command is in the question, tough luck)

Comment: @MultiVAC It is an heuristic algorithm, so it is not really useful to post it here, since I should copy the entire code and is a bit too long ;) But basically it is just vector and matrix computations, without involving environmental items from the OS.

Comment: Because the libraries are getting updated the size will be getting increased and as you are telling that you are generating random nob’s that’s why may be you are getting different output.

Comment: @user2079303 since I use always the same seed for the same random function yes, we can say that it is deterministic, so even with different compiler versions I would expect to have different binaries but with same results: both results are correct, so it is not an undefined behaviour, but they are different.

Comment: @ali786 I don't use any particular library function (sqrt and pow from math, and some string operations). And for the issue due by the random problem, I use my own function.

Comment: @Enne undefined behaviour can very well result in correct answer, but it's not guaranteed to result in the same answer on different compiler.

Comment: @Enne With undefined behaviour it is possible have 2 different, yet correct results. But you don't describe how they are different, yet correct, so we have no tools to help you. That said, it may have something to do with differences in floating point handling.

Comment: @user694733 it is an heuristic optimization algorithm to solve approximately an NP-hard problem: so the results are both solutions of the problem, but their fitness differs

Comment: Are you doing much floating point, and the processor has extended precision (like an Intel)?  In that case, the results may depend on when the compiler spills to memory, and when not (or whether it uses the newer SSE instructions or not).

Comment: @Enne `computation like pow(), sqrt()`  Well, if these operations are an intrinsic part of your algorithm, then it is not surprising you get different results on different versions of the compiler.  This is especially the case if you're testing for equality between floating point computations and the result of such tests determines what part of your code is executed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, this may be true, but for instance in this case I use these functions to compute some values which then I round to integer (by summing +0.5 and truncating by casting) and the algorithm uses only integers.

Comment: @Enne in my experience using casting to round is very prone to errors as it highly depends on you compiler (and compiler settings). For instance, I am currently working with embedded PPC processors and some custom patched GCC version. In this case `int i = (int) d` (where `d` is some double) would result the binary presentation of `d` being stored in `i`. Maybe try using `rint/lrint`. However, I doubt that that's the problem. You might also want to try replacing e.g. `int` with `int32_t` from the `stdint.h` header in cases where you depend on the exact size of the variable.

Comment: Use `uint32_t crt_rand_seed`?

Comment: Ok I've found the old version of MinGW and it works, I'm now able to recompile exactly the same executable that returns the same results. Now the question is: is it possible to extract from the old MinGW version the library files that I use and include them statically in my source? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064486/mingw-with-old-version-libraries

Comment: Which specific functions cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check is the size of int. Your code relies on overflow and the size of integers may matter.

Your code seems to imply that int is at least 32 bit (you use 0x0x269EC3) but maybe you are now compiling with int at 64 bit.

I wouldn't worry about executable file, it's very unlikely you get the same size by two different compilers.

Comment: No, there is no 'overflow'. The arithmetic is `unsigned int`, which is defined to produce a specific result modulo next higher power of two. And I can't imagine OP would accidentally switch to 64 bit. This is not it.

Comment: I didn't say it's an undefined behaviour. The behaviour of an overflow in case of an `unsigned int` depends on the size. That's what I meant.

Comment: Neither did I. I said that there is no 'overflow'. The standard makes it explicitly clear that (quote) 'unsigned arithmetic does not overflow'. Yes, the result depends on the size, but 'overflow' still has nothing whatever to do with it.