# MinGW with old version libraries

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, static-libraries

I want to compile a C source code that use the following libraries:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
```

with MinGW, i.e. `gcc source.c -o executable`

I've the newest MinGW version installed, but I would like to use the libraries provided by an old release of MinGW (I've also installed the old release of MinGW, in another folder of course).

Is that possible? Is there some gcc parameter to indicate to use a specific library folder instead of its default?

Or should I figure out (how?) which libraries I use (including the dependencies of those indicated above), take the corresponding file (like *.h and *.a) and in some way specify in the source code to use them as static library?

In other words my question is: **is it possible to *extract* from the old MinGW release, the files corresponding to the libraries that I need, and to include/link them in some way statically in my source or during the linking process?**

Answer (score 0):

Just copy over the new files with the old files. or replace the old compiler with the new one. now whether there are changes in gcc which will break when using old files is another question.